# How to prevent cache image in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

I use javascript (jquery) to replace the old user's picture with the new one if he uploaded a new picture, but it seem that browser response return `304 Not Modified` then still show the old image from his cache and i want to refresh the page to see the new uploaded picture.

this problem come when i upload the same photo as the old one but cropped it differently wich means that the old and new images have the same name (note: i'm in mode developpement and i think rails add anything to the name of image)

how i can fix this problem ? i use Rails 4 (i already turn off turbolink)